# Count within a time period, a group of a smaller time period

Tags: mysql

Using MySQL, I want to be able to find out if there has been 4 entries within any 5 minute period, within the last 30 minutes, of a certain code.

```
    name     stamp                 code
    a        2013-02-03 13:12:01   red
    b        2013-02-03 13:23:01   red
    c        2013-02-03 13:23:11   red
    d        2013-02-03 13:24:01   green
    e        2013-02-03 13:24:05   red
    f        2013-02-03 13:24:21   red
    g        2013-02-03 13:25:01   red
    h        2013-02-03 13:48:01   red
```

So, at 2013-02-03 13:50:00, I run a query and it returns the # of entries that within the last 30 minutes, there was a group of 4 or more entries that were within a 5 minute block of time and the stamp of the first matching entry, but only for code red entries.

The result I would like using this sample table would be:  5, 2013-02-03 13:23:01

Possible in a single query? Thanks!

EDIT: See any issues with this query?

```
    SELECT COUNT(*), rolling.stamp
    FROM mytable thisrow JOIN mytable rolling 
       ON (thisrow.stamp BETWEEN rolling.stamp AND 
              rolling.stamp + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
    WHERE rolling.stamp >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)
      AND code = 'red'
    GROUP BY 2 HAVING COUNT(*) >= 4
```

When run against the above table, I get the desired "5, 2013-02-03 13:23:01".

P.S. I substituted  '2013-02-03 13:50:00' for the now() for this example

Answer (score 0):

Yup, possible with a `GROUP BY` and a `HAVING`, using some `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` rounding (subtracting `stamp % 300` from `stamp`) to group into blocks of 300 seconds (5 minutes).

```
SELECT COUNT(*), MIN(stamp)
FROM mytable
WHERE stamp >= NOW() - INTERVAL 30 minute
GROUP BY 
    FROM_UNIXTIME(
       UNIX_TIMESTAMP(stamp) - 
       MOD(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(stamp),300)
    )
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 4
```

This assumes that you mean clock blocks rather than rolling blocks, i.e. you want from 00:00:00 to 00:04:59 etc., rather than from 13:23:01 to 13:28:00. This causes some issues with the "30 minutes ago" rule, so you might want to think that one through a bit carefully.

EDIT: Well seeing as you insisted on making it a rolling block... let's add some delicious awfully-performing joining.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), rolling.stamp
FROM mytable thisrow JOIN mytable rolling 
   ON (thisrow.stamp BETWEEN rolling.stamp AND 
          rolling.stamp + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
WHERE rolling.stamp >= NOW() - INTERVAL 30 minute
GROUP BY 2 HAVING COUNT(*) >= 4;
```

If you've an index on `stamp` it'll perform better, but this is effectively a cross-join with horrible, horrible performance, where you're filtering on *n*² rows where *n* is your row count. Don't run this on big tables.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that point in the scenario. It needs to be rolling blocks.  Your example would give me 4 for count (after adding in the code=red requirement) but I'm expecting 5, since there were 5 code red entries within the 5 minutes starting at 13:23:01.

Comment: Wouldn't that group on count(*)? I'll give it a shot but didn't think that was allowed in MySQL

Comment: Yes, silly me. I originally had the `SELECT` clause columns in the other order, and fixed it after re-reading your problem statement. Yes, re-reading. Damn you for being interesting.

Comment: Edited again to put back the `WHERE` clause I'd left out of the second version. Does that mean it worked?

Comment: The query I edited into my original post worked. And I believe it should work for all scenarios I'm concerned with. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Glad to hear it. Welcome to Stack Overflow, and don't forget to mark the correct answers as accepted, and to upvote answers (not only on your own questions) that you find useful and interesting!

Comment: Thanks, I tried but my reputation is not worthy enough yet :)